# ssas restricting access

Tags: security, ssas, restrict

I have a SSAS cube where some users only should be able to see some of the values. It is based on a dimension Country. How do I setup restrictions so that this filtering on countries is always done, even if I done use that dimension. For the moment only restriction is setup on that dimension. And if All is choosen all countries would be included in calculations.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create roles, assign users (preferably user groups) to roles, and configure the dimension members to allow or exclude when the role members browse the cube. You can use Enable Visual Totals to change the All member to display only the aggregate of the members they're allowed to see. If you leave it disabled (the default), then users see the true value for the All member (i.e. the All member includes the total of every member, even the ones the users cannot see).

Basic information is at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174840.aspx.

Here's a video walkthrough: http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/philo589/dimension-security-in-sql-server-analysis-services.

And a readable walkthrough with sample download and screenshots: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1834/introduction-to-dimension-security-in-sql-server-analysis-services-ssas-2005/